# Передача своего объекта из SecondActivity в MainActivity

Tags: android, activity

Проблема :
Есть MainActivity в ней объект класса myData:

```
class myData{
int a;
float b;
myData() { .... }
```

Через MainActivity мы переходим в SecondActivity в котором свой объект myData.

Через текстовые поля на экране мы вводим 2 переменные. s_a , s_b;

Нажимаем кнопку OK и объект myData заносится в массив.

Мы можем заполнять этот массив сколько нам хочется.


**По нажатию на кнопку back (которая на телефоне) мы возвращаемся в MainActivity.**

Вопрос: Как передать объект класса MyData который мы заполнили во второй активности в объект класса myDate в MainActivity, именно там с этими данными будут манипуляции.

Задача просто манипулировать данными, которые находятся в одной активности через другую. 
Intent я пробовал использовать. Но при использовании интента нужно вызывать startActivity а смысл в том что бы данные обновились в MainActivity в методе onResume. Так же желательно эти данные передать из SecondActivity при вызове функции onStop().

И еще. После закрытия SecondActivity тот массив myDate нужно сохранить. Какие есть несложные способы?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то сумбурно написано .
Но если я правильно понял вопрос, то при вызове SecondActivity из MainActivity вам нужно делать это методом `startActivityForResult()` который не только вызовет другую активити , но и обяжет ее вернуть данные в первую .
То , что вторая активити должна вернуть первой пакуется в интент методом `setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)` во второй активити , затем делаешь этой активити `finish()`..
В первой активити переопределяешь метод `onActivityResult()` , это обратный вызов , который передаст в первую активити то , что вы послали из второй интентом.
Здесь не требуются никаких манипуляций ни с `onResume()` ни с `onStop()` , метод обратного вызова сработает в первой , как только вторая активити закроется - в нем и делайте все , что нужно .

смотри [пример](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/68-urok-40.html)

Сохранять свой объект вы можете куда угодно для долгосрочного хранения, в БД , файл или даже SharedPreferences попробовать использовать , хотя они и не для этого . В любом случае придется писать методы преобразования из объекта в хранимые данные и назад . Еще есть вариант использовать ORM , они работают напрямую с объектом и его долгосрочным хранением . Мне например Realm нравиться в последнее время .

PS: если передавать параметры нужно именно через аппаратную кнопку BACK , что весьма диковато , так как обычно значит - Закрыть без изменений , то вам еще надо переопределить метод `onBackPressed()` во второй активити и из него слать setResult()
НО! это крайне неправильный и интуитивно непонятный для пользователя подход , лучше сделать отдельную кнопку на экране по которой будет осуществляться ввод.

Comment: Нет. Передавать нужно не через back. Наверное это мое неправильное понимание finish . Просто мне нужно во втором Activity
заполнить данные , по нажатию кнопки несколько раз. В каком месте тогда вызывать метод finish ? Если он сразу закрывает активность. А мне нужно дать возможность несколько раз нажать кнопку. Кнопка должна быть одна.

Comment: для чего нужно несколько раз нажимать на кнопку ? Вы создаете массив этих объектов ? Сделайте две кнопки: Добавить и отправить , к примеру

Comment: Если кнопка одна , то каким образом вы собираетесь определить , когда заканчивать вводить данные и нужно уже их отправить ? Нужно ввести заранее известное число данных ? С одной кнопкой и произвольным числом данных у вас ничего не получиться реализовать .

Comment: Решил проблему.
Вот такой способ получился, исходя из вашего совета и поправки одной.
Вызываем через startActivityForResult , в SecondActivity по нажатию кнопки считываются строки с EditText , записываются в объект Data,  этот объект добавляется в список ,потом вызывается setResult,. Опять нажатие, та же операция. А отправляется это все дело если прописать метод finish() в методе onPause() - перед закрытием этой активности. Объект Data наследует интерфейс Parcelable.  
Д

Comment: Позже оставлю тут код правильной реализации , может кому пригодиться.
pavlofff спасибо

Comment: не надо вызывать finish() в onPause() , активити и так закрывается и вызовет finish() сама , вы нарушаете этим жизнинный цикл активити.   Не надо после каждого добавления нового объекта в коллекцию вызывать setResult() , делайте это один раз в onPause() .  для поддерживающего сериализацию ArrayList проще использовать Serializable , чем Parcelable

Comment: Сорри , проверил  - в onPause() SetResult() уже не успевает отработать по назначению , тогда , видимо надо переопределить сам метод finish() , вызвав setResult() перед вызовом super.finish() / Вообще такая схема ( отправлять данные по закрытию активити ) во всем ущербна и не очевидна , прямо чтоли никак нельзя сделать нормальную кнопку , типа "отправить" , "закончить" и тп.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте Observer. Например Otto.https://github.com/square/otto